# In the suggested edits list it's hard to see if entry is a Q or A

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, user-experience

When I open https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits and I scroll trough the entries it is not obvious if a entry is a question or an answer. When it is a question, I will evaluate the changes differently than when it is a answer, but I have to open this Q or A in a new tab to find out. Do I miss some icon or notice? Or can we make this more clear?

Answer (score 4):

It's not immediately obvious, but you do get two clues.

1. The text above the original post author's user card will either say *"asked"* or *"answered"* depending on the post type.
2. On some sites, the question's title is colored differently depending on the post type. On Stack Overflow specifically, question links are blue, while answer links are gray.

Comment: Very subtle, both; I was scanning the list just now trying to figure those out!

Comment: The asked/answered is not very useful since I have to scroll down first and then up again to the beginning of the entry.

Comment: @powtac can't you tell by the content?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter No! Because first I validate if the changes (red->green) make sense and not if the content itself makes sense! Even without getting into the content I can decide to approve a change, also on topics I'm not familiar with. When I'm unsure do ignore the entry.

Comment: @powtac hmm I'm not sure I understand. What kind of changes can you validate that don't depend on content but do depend on post type?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter typos, formatting, removing of "Thanks", better language, clean up...

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter sorry, didn't read your question well. I assume none. But it is helpful to know what type of entry it is.